# Creating Background Thread for Core Data writing

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, core-data, save

I'm trying to recreate the three tier core data system that is described in this cocoanetics article ( http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/). The problem I'm running into is creating the private MOC on its own background thread. I don't have much experience with multithreading and how it should be done in objective c. I've been reading over articles and trying to grasp how to correctly implement this approach, but I have finally conceded to the fact that I don't know what I'm doing.

To create this approach, do I need to create an NSThread and manage it? Or is there a simpler way that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to perform Core Data operations in the background is to create a managed object context of the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. This type of MOC creates and manages a private queue. Using `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` to execute operations on the private MOC ensures that the right queue is used.

See [Concurrency Support for Managed Object Contexts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)
in the *Core Data Release Notes for OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0* for details and examples.

I can only recommend to watch the video or slides from the WWDC 2011 Session 303 "￼What’s New in Core Data on iOS", where Core Data concurrency is explained.

Comment: What I'm still stuck wondering is about how all this interacts with a background thread? Does making the managedObjectContext `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` automatically give it a queue that doesn't run on the main thread? I am not understanding something in this setup that allows for the main thread to stay free while working with the core data objects.

Comment: @TheJer: Yes, the private type MOC creates it's own queue that runs on a background thread.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Did I just miss that documentation on everything I read?

Answer (score -3):

Managing threads is very basic in iOS

To have something run on background, you do like this:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    // method is called on main thread normally

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        .... // here things are run in background
    });
}
```

To go back to main thread anywhere, do this:

```
- (void)someOtherMethod {
    // method is called on background thread

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ... // here things are on main thread again
    });
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that when you use dispatch_async there is no guarantee you'll find the same thread? The block is just dispatched to a thread that is able to process it at some time in the future, correct? Using this approach, I don't understand how you could persist a background MOC to use every time you need to write new data into the PSC.

Comment: `NSManagedObjectContext` is not thread-safe normally. So, please, do not do this.