# <<error type>> returned for NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I have an NSFetchRequest that returns multiple NSManagedObjects called "Duty".
If it is successful it returns an array like [Duty].
I want to enumerate over the array and do something with each duty. This is done in a for loop. My problem is that the duty in the loop is returned as `<<error type>>` as seen below:

[image: Explained <<error type>>]

However, if I acces a duty directly by its index in the array it turns out fine as seen below:

```
//Find duties for calendar export
        var dutiesRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        dutiesRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Duty", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

        dutiesRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "startDate", ascending: true)]
        dutiesRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(startDate >= %@) AND (startDate <= %@)", fromDate, toDate)

        var dutiesFetchError : NSError?

        let duties = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(dutiesRequest, error: &dutiesFetchError) as [Duty]

        //If I get the duty by its index it works:
        let duty = duties[0] as Duty
```

Can anyone spot the reason for this? Is my code wrong or may this be a bug in XCode?

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, I should have included all the code as the problem went away when I removed some of the earlier code.
I wanted to make sure the operation was executed not on the main thread so I made a call for another thread like so:

```
class func saveToCalendarInBackground(eventStore:EKEventStore, calendar:EKCalendar, fromDate: NSDate, toDate: NSDate, previousEventIDs: [String:String], managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext, progress: (progress: Float!) -> (), completion:(newEventIDs: [String:String]!, error: NSError!) -> ()) -> Void {

    //Run the operations on another thread (not main), but move the progress and completion closures to the main thread with GCD
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        //Find duties for calendar import
        var dutiesRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        dutiesRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Duty", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

        dutiesRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "startDate", ascending: true)]
        dutiesRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(startDate >= %@) AND (startDate <= %@)", fromDate, toDate)

        var dutiesFetchError : NSError?

        let duties = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(dutiesRequest, error: &dutiesFetchError) as [Duty]

        //If I get the duty by its index it works:
        //let duty = duties[0] as Duty

        if dutiesFetchError == nil {

            for duty in duties {

            }
        }
        else {
            //Return callbacks on main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                completion(newEventIDs: nil, error: NSError(domain: "CalendarManagerDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "Found no duties for calendar export."]))

            })
        }
    })
}
```

If I remove

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { })
```

the for loop finds each duty correctly.

Any explanation for this?

Comment: looks like another swift issue. file a bug because IMO the code looks ok....  move the as [Duty] into the for loop

Comment: Hm, alright! Regarding moving the as [Duty], this will return an array of [AnyObject]?. Should I do as [NSManagedObject] in the executeFetchRequest and as [Duty] in the for loop?

Comment: Do you really get a *compiler error*, or is just Xcode's autocomplete feature failing?

Comment: I get a compiler error If I use the duty object from the for loop. So it's not just the autocomplete feature failing. Thanks for looking into this guys, please see my updated question as I probably left out some important code on my first post.

Comment: @fisher: PLEASE copy/paste your code instead of screenshots!

Comment: @MartinR Very sorry, it was my intention to show how the <<error type>> was presented in the best way. I'll fix that right away!

Comment: @fisher: I have copied your `saveToCalendarInBackground()` function into a Core Data project and defined a `Duty` managed object class. It compiles without any errors or warnings, without any changes to your code.

Comment: @fisher: But note that there are other problems with your code. E.g. the error checking for the fetch request is wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27534104/1187415 for a correct example. – And a managed object context is not thread-safe. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13574638/1187415 for the correct way to execute a fetch request in the background.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I took the question at face value and that was a mistake I guess :D

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @MartinR! Makes more sense. I'll try to study up on the managed object context.